# extract data from a uploaded pdf using django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile returns encoded data

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am uploading a pdf using Djnago 1.10.4 framework,
uploaded file returns objects of django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile

When I am trying to extract the data from the object using type(file_uploaded.file)
I am getting 
 object.
now using file_uploaded.file.read().decode('utf-8') should give me the extracted data from pdf. But I am getting encrypted data in hexadecimal or some thing

```
if request.FILES:
    file_uploaded = request.FILES["file"]
    # file_uploaded = file.name
    print('file_uploaded')
    print(file_uploaded.file.read().decode('UTF-8', errors="ignore"))
    print("file_uploaded.file", type(file_uploaded.file))
    print("file_uploaded", type(file_uploaded))
    file_type = ""
    extn = file_uploaded.name
    file_supported = [".pdf", ".jpg", ".png",".json", ".rtf", ".docx", ".txt", ".csv"]
    extension = '.'+extn.split(".")[1]
    # extension = "." + .split(".")[1]
    if(extension in file_supported):
        for formates in file_supported:
            if (formates == extension):
                file_type = formates[1:]
    else:
         print ('file is not uploaded')
```

above code workes for text files like csv, rft but not working for pdf. Output from pdf file is this

```
              Β-'EMhXmt99*6":ȩ@+6H:yVl=d|9p
  PeǸP|PRMYy+zR!ȷ/,yL=rD>lRM_QhOYO&|C'x.1%V]!pK,KEq㠪HSYO_O
                                                           {
4^R    ς~7އG|䡚wgn˒( pOIUk]CF<~                             (bt 
譌)0vפ/HgDh+刃gzDU;$k-XOeki~kgۍJ_v41"
 WS(X  ]|GQyoZ?uu`^a;v(aiky|RUUSVT@P֯׹PIAZIW-)Ʌb?^mᇏ 
UQbq3D@_J^Hdp7e,2̓\r|/e,vlBHG`-#!K<x1~i>s#cN7iL7QON-Wؖ
```

following is the output from my terminal when csv file uploaded:

```
file_uploaded
3526 HIGH ST,SACRAMENTO,95838,CA,2,1,836,Residential
file_uploaded.file <class '_io.BytesIO'>
file_uploaded 
       <class'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>
```

Please help me on this.